# in ionic 2 what is the real difference between a directive, property, and an attribute?

Tags: properties, attributes, ionic2

So a standard html attribute is one with the attribute name on the left and the value in quotes on the right. (class="buttons")
To change something on an element in Ionic the syntax is value name only, no quotes. 
However I've noticed that sometimes that value is called a directive, other times a property and other times an attribute. What's the difference?

Here are examples of each from the docs :

buttons use a standard  element, but are enhanced with an ion-button **directive**.

```
<button ion-button>Button</button>
```

The color **property** sets the color of the button. Ionic includes a number of default colors which can be easily overridden:

```
<button ion-button **color="light"** >Light</button>
```

// what I consider an attribute is being called a property here.

To use the outline style for a button, just add the outline **property**:

```
 <button ion-button color="light" **outline** >Light Outline</button>  //outline is called a property as well.
```

Add the large **attribute** to make a button larger, or small to make it smaller:

```
<button ion-button **large** >Large</button>
```

//large is being called an attribute here. Why not call it a property or a directive?

Does any of it make a difference or no?

Answer (score 0):

Button is one of Angular components which Ionic is largely consist of. So to get it short:

- `ion-button` is a component which is build upon `[ion-button]` selector as you can find it here in [source](https://github.com/driftyco/ionic/blob/master/src/components/button/button.ts#L124)
- `color`, `outline`, `large` are the inputs of `ion-button` component as you can also see in [source](https://github.com/driftyco/ionic/blob/master/src/components/button/button.ts#L158)

From the DOM point of view all of these are attributes. Although if you really need to have an exact `[attribute]` to be compiled by Angular you've got to use `[attr.attribute]` binding which is not the same for directives/component and its inputs. Inputs are the properties of directives/components at the same time.